# What is the use of callbacks in takepicture()

Tags: android

I am new to android and camera,so not able to understand clearly.
Why is JPEGcallback and Raw Picture callback required in camera takePicture?And how these callBacks are handled?
Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is asyc callback to notify that image data is ready after picture is taken.

So i.e. if you want to store imagedata to jpeg, then use bitmapfactory etc to store in desire format.

similarly if you want to take another picture you should not until this app notify by callback.